# Error de PHP Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un `array` y me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\controllers\Admin.php on line
>   748 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 748
>
> Backtrace:

El `array` va a tener datos que obtengo de la base de datos este es el método donde lo genero:

```
public function teniurtype()
{

            $postData = $this->input->post();
            //$postName = json_decode(stripslashes($postData['roster_salesforcename']));
            $postAdvocate = $postData['sup'];
            $Date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $arrayMtd = array();
            $arrayAdvocates = array();
            $arrayhire_date = array();
            $arrayhire_date = $this->ol_model->gethire_date($postAdvocate);
            $arrayAdvocates = $this->ol_model->getadvocatesSup($postAdvocate);
            $sizeArrAdv = sizeof($arrayAdvocates);
            $bandera = false;
            $dateC = new DateTime($Date);
            $monthC = $dateC->format('m');
            $yearC =  $dateC->format('Y');
            $dayC = $dateC->format('d');
            $Type3 = "T3";
            $Type2 = "T2";
            $Type1 = "T1";
            $monthCn = (int)$monthC;
            $yearCn  = (int)$yearC ;
            $i=0;
            for ($i=0; $i < $sizeArrAdv ; $i++) {
                $Yhire_date = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);
                $Mhire_date = $this->ol_model->getmonthHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);
                $Yhire_daten = (int)$Yhire_date;
                $Mhire_daten = (int)$Mhire_date;
                $u=($yearCn-$Yhire_daten)*12;
                $d=$u+($monthCn-1);
                $t=$d-($Mhire_daten);
                $monthworked =$t;
                //$monthworked = ((($yearC)-($Yhire_date))*12)+($monthC-1)-($Mhire_date);

                if ($monthworked > 11){
                    if($monthworked >= 12 && $monthworked < 18 ){
                        if ($Mhire_date%2==0){
                            $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "70.000");
                        }else{
                            $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "80.000");

                        }
                    }elseif ($monthworked >= 18 && $monthworked < 24) {
                            if ($Mhire_date%2==0){
                                $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "150.000");
                            }else{
                                $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "150.000");


                            }
                    }elseif ($monthworked > 24) {
                            if ($Mhire_date%2==0){
                                $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"],'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "220.000");
                            }else{
                                $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "230.000");
                            }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo 'No cumple el requisito de cantidad de meses trabajados';
                }
                array_push($arrayMtd, $mworked);
        }
        echo json_encode($arrayMtd);
}
```

Comment: Cual es la linea 748

Comment: esta es la linea:                                                                                                             $mworked = array('advocate' => $arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"], 'Hire_Date' => $arrayhire_date[$i]["roster_hire_date"], 'Tenure' => $monthworked, 'Type' => $Type3, 'Bono' => "230.000");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error parece estar en el model donde haces la consulta, está retornando un Objeto en vez de un Array. busca algo parecido a esto:

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
return $result->result_array();
```

si  fuera:  `return $result;` te salta el error mas adelante al querer usarlo como array

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
$arrayhire_date = $this->ol_model->gethire_date($postAdvocate);
$arrayAdvocates = $this->ol_model->getadvocatesSup($postAdvocate);
```

Cambia estas lineas por:

```
$arrayhire_date = $this->ol_model->gethire_date($postAdvocate)->result_array();
$arrayAdvocates = $this->ol_model->getadvocatesSup($postAdvocate)->result_array();
```

En la linea 748 te refieres a estas varibles como arrays, pero son objetos.  Para eso sirve result_array().  Alternativamente, puedes referirte a las variables con -> en lugar the brackets.